# swift iOSアプリで横画面のみの表示をしたい

Tags: ios

swift(device target11以上)でiOSアプリで横画面のみの表示をしたいと感がています。
iPhoneの場合、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

のように「Landscape Left」と「Landscape Right」のチェックを入れれば希望の動作をしれるのですが、iPadの場合は有効ではないようです。

どうすれば横画面固定(ホームボタンが左or右)にできるのでしょうか。
ご存知の方、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プロジェクト画面の`General`→`Deployment info`の上から2番目に`Devices`というポップアップがあります。
ここの`iPhone`, `iPad`, `Universal`をそれぞれ選んで、
全デバイス種ごとにその下の`Device Orientation`から`Portrait`と`Updide Down`のチェックをはずし、`Landscape Left`と`Landscape Right`のみにチェックが入っている状態にすれば良いのでは無いでしょうか